# Couldn't find node output - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node and JS, When I tried to print the basic console.log() I couldn't find the output, I accidentally deleted the environment path(recovered later) and I thought it was the problem, but even after resetting my PC, I am still getting the same problem. When I use Javascript debug terminal it works, I dont know why it is not working in Powershell. Here the images of my problem.

[Code and terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD1mT.png)

[user variable path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abdSH.png)

[system variable path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOEa7.png)

Comment: Can you run `node` and js code inside of it?

Comment: as i see you haven't save the file yet

Comment: @DadiBit If you mean inside JavaScript Debug Terminal, yes it works.

Comment: @EkaCipta Hey thanks for the help, it printed the console, and how did you find out it is not saved, and also, the tab where it shows didn't change to node and still remained as power shell, but it printed, will that be a problem in future, sorry if my questions are dumb, I am new to Node and also for programming.

Comment: @rajeevisukapatla I meant that you should have tried running only `node` (without any argument) inside of powershell. To answer your other question: when you write `node index.js` you're simply saying: "Hey run the node.js executable (`node`) and tell it to read code from `index.js`". After the code runs it goes back to powershell, so you can write other commands.

Comment: @DadiBit Thank you so much for your reply, as a newbie, I am glad to find people like you who put extra effort into teaching us.